# Place a file in APPDIR from a Custom Action in Advanced Installer

Tags: c#, file, path, custom-action, advanced-installer

Is it possible to place a file, created/modified from a Custom Action, in the `APPDIR`? Or some sort of workaround? I'm wondering if I have to make a XCOPY in my Team Build code, to move the file manually.

The Directory ("APPDIR") doesn't exists at the time i'm trying.

I've move my Custom Action to "Finish Dialogs Stage" and it's execution Time is Immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add your custom action as **deferred** and with **no impersonation** after the Install Execution Stage -- Add Resources action. Maybe your custom action needs more rights to create the file.

Comment: I can't access public properties like session["APPDIR"] or session["MyProp1"] in a deferred CA. I need the path and the properties I want to encrypt to complete the action. In what approach would you tackle this situation? :)

Comment: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-access-property-deferred-action.html

Comment: 4 days of struggle is finally over, thanks it works now :)
I also added this to pass the public properties to the deferred CA.
                var delimiter = '|';
                var actionData = session["CustomActionData"];
                var dataArray = actionData.Split( delimiter );
                foreach (var d in dataArray)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Property: " + d);
                }

Comment: indeed during the deferred execution the installer properties lifecycle is ended. The only way to access them will be to set them in the CustomActionData property (this is a special property available during the deferred execution mode too) and access the CustomActionData property value.

Comment: My prototype worked with an Attach DLL, where it was easy to reference a path to the dll, in a folder i just made,  on the machine AI are installed. Should I use a Call a standard DLL instead in production? I'm having trouble setting the path. I tryed [APPDIR]\bin\mydll.dll. Before adding [APPDIR] i got a no dll found, now I don't get an error, but the function doesn't seem to be called.